# To redirect all http request to https along with appending index.php to it

Tags: redirect, https, http-redirect

This is my current htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# Apache config
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|php)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
##<IfModule mod_expires.c>
##ExpiresActive On
##ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
##ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
##ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
##ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
##ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
##ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
##ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
##ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
##ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
##ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
##ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
##</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I tried appending

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but it is not workking. The issue is according to the current htacess file it redirects all the requests to index.php.
So how can I achieve the redirection to https and index.php both together.
Please help me with the code. IT would be a great help

Comment: This has nothing to do with php in the end, please remove that tag. Thanks.

Comment: The redirection has to be implemented _before_ the internal rewrite, so further up in your distributed configuration file (".htaccess").

Comment: @arkascha Thanks. It solved my problem. 
The final solution to my problem is 
`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: I wrote the redirection should be implemented before, so above the internal rewriting. You placed it below. That will indeed work, but it results in additional redirections. You can confirm that using either your http server's access log file or your browsers console.

Comment: Yeah I saw and the above code which I mentioned in the comment is not working fine. Also there are multiple redirections. So can you help me with the correct code?

Comment: The code I mentioned in the question is the current code. But not I want to force all the requests to https keeping the current iinternal rewrite. How can I achieve both?

Comment: As written: implement the redirection from http to https first in the configuration file, then the internal rewriting rules.

Comment: I tried adding this but it didnot worked.
`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`
It didnot redirect to https

Answer (score 0):

This should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

*And a personal remark*: Please don't get this wrong. But this question reads as if you never bothered to take a single look into the documentation of the tool you are using. Why not? It is, as typical for OpenSource, of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I tried the above given code and it worked for the https redirection but due to this all the POST method calls have stopped working. The $_POST variable always turns out to be null due to this. I am beginner to this. So it would be great if you can guide me over this

Comment: I suspect that you are using URLs as references... So something like ´<form ... method="post" action="http://example.com/post.php">`, at least that would explain what you describe?

Comment: Yes. I have the same code structure that you mentioned.

Comment: Then you need to change that. It makes no sense. Trying to fix that _afterwards_ won't work. the "action" property in a form tag should bei either a relative or an absoolute path. but _not_ a URL!